# Airflow: Cannot run dynamically mapped task manually

Tags: dynamic, airflow, task

I'm using Airflow's Dynamic Task Mapping.
I wanna run only one mapped task manually by clicking 'Run' button below, but it gives me an error.
"Could not queue task instance for execution, task instance is missing"
[image]
[image]

I can run other tasks in the same DAG manually except for this one.

1. Isn't there any way to run certain task that has been dynamically mapped ?
   Airflow document dosen't tell me anything about this... (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html)
2. What does it mean "task instance is missing"?